# Laravel: Can't use the autoload function

Tags: laravel, autoload

I have a question about autoloading in Laravel.

I am trying to use an API to translate a web site. I typed in the code given by the provider in the controller and I got the following error message.

> require(vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is the code.

```
require 'vendor\autoload.php';    <=★Here★

session_start();

define('URL', '');
define('KEY', '');
define('SECRET', '');
define('NAME', '');

$api_name = '';
$api_param = '';

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider(
    [
        'clientId'                => KEY,                            
        'clientSecret'            => SECRET,                         
        'redirectUri'             => '',                             
        'urlAuthorize'            => '',                             
        'urlAccessToken'          => URL . '/oauth2/token.php',      
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    ],
);

try {

    // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials');

    // The provider provides a way to get an authenticated API request for
    // the service, using the access token; it returns an object conforming
    // to Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface.

    $params = array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken->getToken(),                   
        'key' => KEY,                                                 
        'api_name' => $api_name,
        'api_param' => $api_param,
        'name' => NAME,                                               
        'type' => 'xml',                                              
        'xxx' => 'xxx',                                               
    );

    $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
        'POST',
        URL . '/api/?' . http_build_query($params),                    
        $accessToken,
    );

    $response = $provider->getResponse($request);
    $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    print_r($data);

} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {

    // Failed to get the access token or user details.
    exit($e->getMessage());

}
```

I checked the file pointed out in the error message and actually autoload.php file was in the vendor folder. I did some research and I found some web sites saying that I should add a directory in composer.json but I wasn't so sure what I should do.

I appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should do. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Laravel already uses composer/autoloading, you should just be able to skip that line.

Comment: You don't need to autoload in controller - Laravel did it himself. You must rewrite this code to use with Laravel.

Comment: @broombeer
Thank you for your comment! I deleted the line you pointed out and now the website is throwing back "invalid_client". Do you know what this is due to?